# Getting "new-line character seen in unquoted field" when parsing csv document using django-storages

Tags: django, csv, amazon-s3, django-storage

I am trying to parse csv files that have been uploaded to Amazon S3 using django-storages.  I keep getting a "Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?".  The normal work around for this is to open the file with "rU", but that does not seem to work with django storages.  If I drop the file directly on the server and open from there it works, I just want to avoid storing the files directly on the server if possible.  Here is the code I am using:

```
import csv
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as s3_storage
n = 'csvdumps/130331548894.csv'
csvf = s3_storage.open(n, "rU")
csvReader = csv.reader(csvf)
for item in csvReader:
    print item
```

Answer (score 3):

I can see that this is a django-storage reported bug here http://jgrid.org/david/django-storages/issue/80/trying-to-parse-csv-file-from-django but perhaps you can try this:-

```
csvf = s3_storage.open(n.splitlines(), "rU")
```

Would also be great if you could share a link to access some of your S3 (sample) csv files though so I can open them to check the line endings.