# new-line character seen in unquoted field

Tags: python, django

I have a file loaded in memory from a Django form. It is giving me the following error:

```
new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

Another solution used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745557/getting-new-line-character-seen-in-unquoted-field-when-parsing-csv-document-us).

However, i already have the file in memory so i require to change it to opening in `"rU"` format.

This is my relevant code in `views.py`

```
form = ResultsUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        reader = csv.reader(request.FILES['file'])
        for row in reader:
            #etc...
```

Does anyone know how to go about fixing this? The error is thrown from this statement `for row in reader:`

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSV new-line character seen in unquoted field error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315635/csv-new-line-character-seen-in-unquoted-field-error)

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341174/upload-and-parse-csv-file-with-universal-newline-in-python-on-google-app-engin

Comment: Looks like we have duplicates on this issue everywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [csv file uploading error in Django in Mac: new-line character seen in unquoted field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404339/csv-file-uploading-error-in-django-in-mac-new-line-character-seen-in-unquoted-f)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404339/csv-file-uploading-error-in-django-in-mac-new-line-character-seen-in-unquoted-f?rq=1)

The issue was how i was saving the .csv file. When producing a .csv file in excel for mac save it as "Windows Comma Separated Values (.csv)" This will stop the addition of unwanted characters that throw of `import csv` in Django and python.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the read mode to 'rU' instead of 'r' or 'rb'

Answer (score 1):

This is how I avoided the above error while reading from the uploaded CSV file that contains some special symbols also.

```
def utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data): //encodes the Unicode strings as UTF-8 
    for line in unicode_csv_data:
        yield line.encode('utf-8')


def validate_csv(request):
    csv_contents = request.FILES['files'].read().decode('utf-8-sig') // to avoid csv exception while reading unwanted characters (eg: \xef\xbb\xbf)
    request_file = csv_contents.splitlines()
    dict_reader = csv.DictReader(utf_8_encoder(request_file)) // avoid error - ascii' codec can't encode character u'\\ufeff' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
    #because data contain some special symobls like G�mez
    fieldnames = dict_reader.fieldnames //fieldnames contain column header
    for item in dict_reader:
        #etc...
```

Answer (score -2):

Check with the header line in csv file.It should be exact same as the column name.